# Direct2D1 wave pattern with animated turbulence offset

Tags: c#, .net, direct2d, vortice

I'm trying to reproduce the following effect using Direct2D1:

[image]

I thought it would be a *"simple"* case of using the [built-in turbulence effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/turbulence), and adjusting the offset property, as the documentation says:

> Offset
> `D2D1_TURBULENCE_PROP_OFFSET`
>
> The coordinates where the turbulence output is generated. The algorithm used to generate the Perlin noise is position dependent, so a different offset results in a different output. This property is not bounded and the units are specified in DIPs.
>
> Note: **The offset does not have the same effect as a translation because the noise function output is infinite and the function will wrap around the tile.**

Using my home-made C#/Wind32 framework and the [Vortice](https://github.com/amerkoleci/Vortice.Windows/) wrapper around Direct2D, I coded this simple turbulence effect:

```cs
public void OnRender(ID2D1DeviceContext g, float t) {
   using var turbulenceEffect = new Turbulence(g) {
      Offset = new Vector2(t, 0)
   };

   g.Clear(Colors.Black);
   g.DrawImage(turbulenceEffect);
}
```

However, the render outputs a turbulence image slowly crawling rightward, acting as if the turbulence offset was indeed a translation, unlike what I understand from the documentation quoted above.

Could it be a bug of the D2D wrapper? Is my understanding of the docs incorrect? If not, what would be the correct way to implement the desired effect?

---

[Reference image source](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/fractal-noise-s-offset-turbulence-has-maximum-value-how-can-i-keep-going/m-p/11302493#M117629)
[Vortice.Direct2D1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vortice.Direct2D1/) 2.4.2
.NET Target Framework: `net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0`

Comment: I'm coding in C#, but I can read C++.

Comment: Noise will not create any fancy effect, it's *"a pseudo-random function whose value depends on the frequency, position, and seed value"* as the doc says. So, changing "offset", as the name implies will just compute another "portion" of the (frequency + seed) "ribbon" portion.  So indeed, if you do this `DrawImage(fx, targetOffset: new(-offset, 0));` it will scroll.

Comment: It indeed scrolls... So I guess my understanding of the documentation was incorrect.